# How to prevent stale update on a record in Mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I choose old approach by matching the document's modified time stamp on query and entry in database on a document using Java. Is there a better way recommended or Mongo provides any such feature?

Below is code snipped of what I am doing.

1) Data in Mongo for Document TestDoc

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("568ad7d4ab590644c4bf08c2"),
"_class" : "com.test.TestData",
"creationDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T20:36:36.290Z"),
"modifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T14:36:36.290Z"),
"applicationNumber" : "Test123454" }
```

2) In Java -

a) retrieve the document matching to update request

```
testDoc = db.test.find("_id": testDoc.getId();
```

b) compare the modified timestamp on update request with doc retrieved from database

```
if (testDoc.getModifiedDate.equals())  { //update document }
   else { //Stale record - Throw an exception }
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: 1) Data in Mongo :                                                                                             {
 "_id" : ObjectId("568ad7d4ab590644c4bf08c2"),
    "_class" : "com.test.TestData",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T20:36:36.290Z"),
 "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T14:36:36.290Z"),
    "applicationNumber" : "Test123454"
}

Comment: 1) Data in Mongo for Document TestDoc
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("568ad7d4ab590644c4bf08c2"),
    "_class" : "com.test.TestData",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T20:36:36.290Z"),
 "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-01-04T14:36:36.290Z"),
    "applicationNumber" : "Test123454" }
2) In java - 
 a) retrieve the document matching to update request
    testDoc = db.test.find("_id": testDoc.getId();   
    b) compare the modified timestamp on update request with doc retrieved from database
   if (testDoc.getModifiedDate.equals())  { //update document }
    else { //Stale record - Throw an exception }

Comment: No worries, I'd recommend editing your post, though instead of commenting. It makes it easier for people to read